# How to run only block of code in PyCharm like in Spyder?

Tags: python, pycharm

In Spyder I can run only a part of code without running everything. I know that in PyCharm I can click right mouse button and "Execute Selection in Console", but it will be new execution without values and variables which declared before this part of code.
So, very often I need to run only few last lines of my code, with parametres and options that I already have.

Comment: Try selecting the declaration lines as well as the ones you want to execute?

Comment: did you try the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use the interactive interpreter while in debug mode.
I find it to be very useful when trying to run code snippets in the program.
view the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Run cell" functionality and the cell will be executed in the Python Console (the same way it does when right clicking "Execute Selection in Console"). To enable that I am aware of two options :

1. In settings (Ctrl+Alt+S) install the "PyCharm cell mode" plugin.
   [image]

Then use ## to create code sections.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7858-pycharm-cell-mode

2. Create a new project in scientific mode (only available in PyCharm professional)
   [image]

You can create code cells with #%%.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html

In both cases, it creates cells that you can execute with the green "play" button like shown below :
[image]